# How do I open up my MySQL on my Raspberry Pi for Outside / Remote Connections?

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, remote-connection

I have a Raspberry Pi that stores temperature data for homebrewing activity. I am making a Spring MVC application on my computer and I want to tap the data. Both my Pi and my computer are on the local network. I can SSH and FTP into my RPi perfectly.

```
mysql --192.168.1.102 --u root -p db
```

Causes a "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.102'".

My Java application isn't connecting either, obviously.

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'port' ;
```

returns the default port, 3306.

Is there a setting that must be enabled to allow remote connections into MySQL?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have recently had the same problem myself. I got it working by doing the following:

**Edit MySQL configuration**

By default, MySQL is not configured to accept remote connections. You can enable remote connections by modifying the configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Find the `[mysqld]` section. The line you need to alter is `bind-address`, which should be set to the default value of `127.0.0.1`. You want to edit this line to instead show the IP of your RPi on the network (which would seem to be 192.168.1.102 from your example). Write the changes.

**Restart the MySQL service**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**Setup MySQL permissions**

Connect to your MySQL instance as root:

```
mysql -p -u root
```

Create a user:

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'<ip_address>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

- The apostrophes ( ' ) in the syntax are required
- The IP address is the IP address of the device on the network you are trying to connect from

Grant permissions to the relevant databases and tables:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database>.* TO '<username>'@'<ip_address>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

- The parameters are those you used to create your user in the previous step
- The * will grant access to all tables within the specified database. Alternatively you could specify a specific table
- You'd probably want to firm up the security by only granting relevant privileges, but that should be enough to test that it works

That should hopefully do it!

Comment: Why is the whole of stack overflow filled with bullshit when the underappreciated answer is right here?

Comment: Don't you need to do in addition `flush privileges;` ?

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me, courtesy of a comment found on [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/) instructable:

1. Grant access to your remote machine using: `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password_here';` (I used 192.168.1.% so that any computer on my network can connect to it)
2. Go into the my.cnf file (`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`) file and look for "bind-address" and comment this out (put a # in front of the line)
3. Reload MySQL config (`service mysql reload`)
4. Restart MySQL server (`service mysql restart`)

Answer (score 4):

If your issue is not able to remotely connect with MySQL on Raspberry Pi, then try below steps. I had the same issue and got it resolved by performing below commands.

1) `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

2) `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1`     // comment this line out

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0          //add this line just below above line
```

3) `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`  //restart mysql

4) `sudo mysql -u root -p`          //login to mysql cli as user 'root'

5) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'beta' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Here 'root' is the mysql user and 'beta' is the password and here privileges are set for 'root'.Change it accordingly and execute above query in mysql cli.

Good Luck !!!