# MySQL connection ERROR 2003 (HY000): <IP Address> (110)

Tags: mysql, xampp, raspberry-pi

I have searched and seen a lot of questions and answers for this error but none of them worked for me.
I have my MySQL in my laptop via Xampp and wanted to connect my Raspberry Pi to it using a direct LAN connection (ethernet cable). Whenever I enter `mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.1.47`on my Raspberry pi, after typing my password, there is a long pause, then the error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server (110)` shows up. Any help please? If you need more information, just ask and tell me what commands to input to show them, I'm still a beginner.

Also, I have commented the `bind-address` in the my.cnf but still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to establish is a remote connection. The default configuration of MySQL doesn't allow it. It's best to configure MySQL that it allows remote connection. Here is an other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733802/how-do-i-open-up-my-mysql-on-my-raspberry-pi-for-outside-remote-connections) with detailed answer about configuring MySQL to allow remote connection from the Raspberry Pi device to a MySQL server.

Also, don't forget to check the firewall rules from your computer.

Comment: Thanks, going to read the SO question after school. About the firewall, does disabling it enough?