# Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi 3 MySQL via weaved (remote access) or from Pi"s IP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, connection

I am kind of new in the world of Raspberry Pi and Linux in general and I've run into a problem.

I installed weaved to have remote access to my raspberry Pi on my other computers. I have access to the web pages ive put in the Pi's www folder , phpmyadmin and page with php script (without SQL). However, as soon as page need a SQL connection, no information is displayed at all and I don't receive an error either. The same problem happen if I type the IP address of the Pi in the URL. Those pages works on localhost thought. The problem seems very similar to this post [How do I open up my MySQL on my Raspberry Pi for Outside / Remote Connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733802/how-do-i-open-up-my-mysql-on-my-raspberry-pi-for-outside-remote-connections) but after trying the first solution and second solution, it doesn't work at all.

Any idea of what would be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is not able to remotely connect with MySQL on Raspberry Pi, then try below steps. I had the same issue and got it resolved by performing below commands.

1) `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

2) `# bind-address = 127.0.0.1`     // comment this line out

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0          //add this line just below above line
```

3) `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`  //restart mysql

4) `sudo mysql -u root -p`          //login to mysql cli as user 'root'

5) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'beta' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Here 'root' is the mysql user and 'beta' is the password. Change it accordingly and execute above query in mysql cli.