# Connecting c# program with MySQL database on raspberry pi. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, database, raspberry-pi

I'am trying to connect MySQL database from raspberry pi to C# Windows Form Application. I'am always getting error

> Projekt.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
>
> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll

Everything is hooked up to router. Both raspberry pi and pc have static ip's. When i tried to launch database with XAMPP on pc, program was able to connect and edit tables. It is worth mentioning that my primitive email server, also hosted on raspberry pi, works over my local network and use MySQL databases in some degree.

Here is part of C# program:

```
namespace Projekt
{
 class DBConnect
 {
    public MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string port;
    private string database;
    private string userid;
    private string password;

    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "192.168.0.120";
        port = "3306";
        database = "project";
        userid = "root";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + userid + ";" + "Pwd=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection to database
    public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

Rest of this file contains inserting, updating etc.

Here is my /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently 
parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
skip-name-resolve

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 192.168.0.120
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#slow_query_log      = 1
#long_query_time = 2
#log_queries_not_using_indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for 
replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

I've tried creating new users, giving them all privileges and setting host as both % and 192.168.0.102 which is my pc's ip in local network. Still the same error.

Does somebody have an idea how to connect those bastards?

If so, could it also be used int external networks? I have already domain at noip.com by the way.

Comment: Can you ping the raspberry pi's IP?

Comment: Yes, raspberry pi respond to ping.

Comment: Likely a fiirewall doing its job on the Pi, i.e. Networking problem. Have you tried e.g. Telnet (or putty telnet) to the Pi port 3306? Just being able to connect is what you want.

Comment: Check out this SO article.  Could be a config issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733802/how-do-i-open-up-my-mysql-on-my-raspberry-pi-for-outside-remote-connections

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrRQcZeXUhQ
I have found this video that explain everything. Like @barny said, firewall problem.
Thanks all for help, maybe somebody will benefit froms this too