# Why are apostrophes required in Create user syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, mariadb

I have seen in the answer supplied in the question:
[How do I open up my MySQL on my Raspberry Pi for Outside / Remote Connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733802/how-do-i-open-up-my-mysql-on-my-raspberry-pi-for-outside-remote-connections#18934943)

And on other sites that the apostrophes ( ' ) in the create user syntax are required.

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But i have found that when the apostrophes are omitted around the username and host name it still works.

for example:

```
CREATE USER jeffrey@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or even

```
CREATE USER jeffrey@127.0.0.1 IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

will generate a user without problems as far as i can tell.

[image: Image of create user syntax]

[image: Image of result of create user syntax]

Is this behavior intended or is it bad to do it this way (omitting apostrophes)?

Regards

Comment: Thanks, has been searching for a while, but couldn't find the exact page with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html:

> The user name and host name need not be quoted if they are legal as
>   unquoted identifiers. Quotes are necessary to specify a `user_name`
>   string containing special characters (such as space or -), or a
>   `host_name` string containing special characters or wildcard characters
>   (such as . or %); for example, `'test-user'@'%.com'`.

So presumably you couldn't use the name `table` without quoting it:

```
CREATE USER table@127.0.0.1 ...
```

But you can use `foobar`:

```
CREATE USER foobar@127.0.0.1 ...
```